# Undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User.Railstutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I try create session as in example 'railstutorial' book.But where I did wrong and can't find where error.
This is my session_helper

```
      def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
      end

      def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
      end

      def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
      end

      def current_user
        remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
      end

    end
```

this is my Controller sessions_controller

```
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

and this is my Model users.rb

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token

      validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 2 }, uniqueness: true
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
      has_secure_password

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

it is full error message from console

```
2.1.2 :004 > user.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'anna' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('qwerty@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x000000026f58b8>
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:211:in `method_missing'
    from /home/weare138/app/myapp/app/models/user.rb:24:in `create_remember_token'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:483:in `create_or_update'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
... 17 levels...
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/weare138/app/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.1.2 :005 >
```

how fix it?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can we have the complete error (and not just the truncated one in the question title)?

Comment: Oh and another thing, do you use `att_reader` or `attire_`something in your `User` model?

Comment: ok, update message.No, I am not use attr_reader.I must add him?

Comment: No you should not use it if your class is extending `ActiveRecord::Base`. ActiveRecord automatically creates getter and setter for all Database columns. For this reason is strange that this method is missing. Is `remember_token` a column in the User table? Did you manually add this column or did you use a migration?

Comment: hmm, it seems I added. but table 'users' in shema.rb not has column 'remember_token', only string 'name', 'email', 'password_digest'

Comment: So this is the problem, your schema is not alined ;) and ActiveRecord can't create the getter and setter methods. Just rollback and migrate again your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `ActiveRecord::Base` can't find the column `remember_token` in the user table, this can be due to the schema not correctly aligned with the DB.
Try rollbacking and re-migrating your DB and see if this fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this to your User model:

```
attr_accessor :remember_token
.
.
.
def remember
  self.remember_token = ...
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, ...)
end
```

Comment: Am I wrong saying that this should not be necessary if using ActiveRecord::Base?